# Connecting to hive from windows using pyhive and pyodbc

Tags: python, hive

Hi I want to connect to hive using python libraries pyhive and pyodbc:

```
     conn = hive.Connection(host="hostname",port=10001,username="********",database="default",auth='KERBEROS',kerberos_service_name="hive")
```

the error I am getting

```
     TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'
```

And When I am using pyodbc then

```
conn_string="""DSN=%s; Host=%s, Port=%d, Database=default; AuthMech=3;UseSASL=1; UID=%s; PWD=%s; SSL=1;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1"""% (cfg['DSN'], cfg['host'], cfg['port'],cfg['username'], cfg['password'])

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, autocommit=True)
```

This is the error I am getting so Please if anyone who has been successful in connecting python with hive by pyodbc, pyhive Please Help

Hive is hosted in Cloudera.

Comment: did you tried this. https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/161

Comment: Hi Solved the issue just created an odbc DSN then its working

Comment: `impyla` is an alternative to `pyhive` -- and it's maintained by Cloudera, which might help in your case...

Answer (score 0):

pyhive needs sasl dependencies

on linux install by yum/apt

on windows after install package cyrus-sasl, need to configure sasl2 directory
located `site-packages/sasl` or `Library/bin/`

method 1: copy sasl2 folder to C:\CMU\bin\

method 2: add registry string

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Carnegie Mellon\Project Cyrus\SASL Library\SearchPath
C:\Users\cdarling\Miniconda3\envs\hive\Library\bin\sasl2
```